# Python Regex - Parsing HTML

Tags: python, html, regex

I have this little code and it's giving me AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.

```
import sys
import re

#def extract_names(filename):

f = open('name.html', 'r')
text = f.read()

match = re.search (r'<hgroup><h1>(\w+)</h1>', text)
second = re.search (r'<li class="hover">Employees: <b>(\d+,\d+)</b></li>', text)  

outf = open('details.txt', 'a')
outf.write(match)
outf.close()
```

My intention is to read a .HTML file looking for the `<h1>` tag value and the number of employees and append them to a file. But for some reason I can't seem to get it right.
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that some higher level libraries like Scrapy of Beautiful Soap would fit better your task than regular expressions.

Comment: @larsmans: the myriad others also include [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491) which actually demonstrates how it is possible to parse HTML with regexes. And Helen's task right here is teeny-tiny compared to that. So not so trigger-happy.

Comment: It’s a shame you can’t use `vi` to edit HTML files, innit?

Comment: If you show the relevant portions of the HTML file you are looking at, it would help a great deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of completion: your error message just indicate that your regular expression failed and did not return anything...

Answer (score 6):

You are using a regular expression, but matching XML with such expressions gets too complicated, too fast. Don't do that.

Use a HTML parser instead, Python has several to choose from:

- [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is part of the standard library
- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a popular 3rd party library
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a fast and feature-rich C-based library.

The latter two handle malformed HTML quite gracefully as well, making decent sense of many a botched website.

ElementTree example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('filename.html')
for elem in tree.findall('h1'):
    print ElementTree.tostring(elem)
```

Comment: Better use BeatifulSoup or `lxml.html` for HTML files, though -- more often than not, they're malformed XML.