# count the number of images on a webpage, using urllib

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing, urllib

For a class, I have an exercise where i need to to count the number of images on any give web page. I know that every image starts with , so I am using a regexp to try and locate them. But I keep getting a count of one which i know is wrong, what is wrong with my code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import re
img_pat = re.compile('<img.*>',re.I)

def get_img_cnt(url):
  try:
      w =  urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  except IOError:
      sys.stderr.write("Couldn't connect to %s " % url)
      sys.exit(1)
  contents =  str(w.read())
  img_num = len(img_pat.findall(contents))
  return (img_num)

print (get_img_cnt('http://www.americascup.com/en/schedules/races'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh regular expressions.

Your regex pattern `<img.*>` says "Find me something that starts with `<img` and stuff and make sure it ends with `>`.

Regular expressions are greedy, though; it'll fill that `.*` with literally everything it can while leaving a single `>` character somewhere afterwards to satisfy the pattern. In this case, it would go all the way to the end, `<html>` and say "look! I found a `>` right there!"

You should come up with the right count by making `.*` non-greedy, like this:

`<img.*?>`

Comment: thanks that does work. I don't understand what the ? is doing?

Comment: It says to the regex to stop the search at the first `>` encounters, not the latest. So it will catch every `<img />` and not just a big `<img />` (which could contains other <img inside...)

Comment: The `?` tells the regular expression to match the arbitrary `.*` pattern with as _few_ characters as possible, rather than as _many_ (which is the default). So if we personify regex a bit longer, it would see `<img` and then look for a `>` as soon as it possibly could to end that match.

Answer (score 10):

Don't ever use regex for parsing HTML, use an html parser, like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Here's a working example, how to get `img` tag count using `BeautifulSoup` and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_img_cnt(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    return len(soup.find_all('img'))


print(get_img_cnt('http://www.americascup.com/en/schedules/races'))
```

Here's a working example using `lxml` and `requests`:

```
from lxml import etree
import requests


def get_img_cnt(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    root = etree.fromstring(response.content, parser=parser)

    return int(root.xpath('count(//img)'))


print(get_img_cnt('http://www.americascup.com/en/schedules/races'))
```

Both snippets print `106`.

Also see:

- [Python Regex - Parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513401/python-regex-parsing-html)
- [Python regular expression for HTML parsing (BeautifulSoup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391/python-regular-expression-for-html-parsing-beautifulsoup)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is greedy, so it matches much more than you want. I suggest using an HTML parser.

`img_pat = re.compile('<img.*?>',re.I)` will do the trick if you must do it the regex way. The `?` makes it non-greedy.

- A good website for checking what your regex matches on the fly: http://www.pyregex.com/
- Learn more about regexes: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html