# Python regex url grab

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing, wildcard

I am having trouble figuring out how to select part of an html link using regex

say the link is:

```
<a href="race?raceid=1234">Mushroom Cup</a>
```

I have figured out how to get the race id, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use a regular expression to find just 'Mushroom cup'. The best I can do is get 1234>Mushroom Cup.

I'm new to regular expressions and it is just too much for me to comprehend.

Comment: How much could the input vary? If you're extracting this data from several places in a large document, it might be worth using an HTML parser instead of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something very much like

```
re.findall('<a href="race\?raceid=(\d+)">([^<]+)</a>',html_text)
```

Comment: I am having trouble downloading beautiful soup (I have anaconda python package distribution), so thank you for this regex answer

Comment: please don't use regex for parsing html :)

Comment: if thats really all he needs its pretty easy to get with a regex ... although in general I certainly agree

Comment: @JoranBeasley yeah, I'll put you +1 for being nice to the OP and me :D

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever use regex for parsing HTML. Instead use HTML parsers like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Here's an example using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<html>
<head>
    <title>Python regex url grab - Stack Overflow</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="race?raceid=1234">Mushroom Cup</a>
</body>
</html
""")

link = soup.find('a')
par = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(link.attrs['href']).query)
print par['raceid'][0]   # prints 1234
print link.text   # prints Mushroom Cup
```

Note, that `urlparse` is used for getting link parameter's value. See more here: [Retrieving parameters from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074803/retrieving-parameter-from-url-in-python).

Also see:

- [Python Regex - Parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513401/python-regex-parsing-html)
- [Python regular expression for HTML parsing (BeautifulSoup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391/python-regular-expression-for-html-parsing-beautifulsoup)

Hope that helps.

Comment: oh...that seems nicer

Comment: +1 since I agree in general that parsing html with a regex is a bad idea, but it would be nice to demonstrate why this solution may be superior than the simple regex for the OP's question.  I know there are several reasons not to use regex (mainly that html is a nested language and regex doesnt handle nesting so well (stateless))